# How to add custom domain brought from hostinger to my glitch.com app?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I've brought a domain from hostinger and I want to add that domain to the app I hosted in glitch.com but even after following glitch's documentation my custom domain wont work after configuring dns in hostinger.

Here is what glitch shows me when I add a custom domain:

[image]

The glitch says that the domain is currently registered and it gives me a point to link to add in DNS in hostinger. But hostinger also asks type which I am setting as CNAME and a **Name**, I don't know what to put in Name section:

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should set "Type" to "CNAME", name to "www", and "Points to" to "glitch.edgeapp.net" and you should then be good to go. DNS changes can take some time to change, so if you don't see an instant update keep that in mind.